# Solving the first exercise on "Pandoc Filters" page

Tags: lua, markdown, pandoc

The first question on https://pandoc.org/filters.html#exercises asks to convert all text to uppercase except if it is part of a URL or a link title. So, I read the discussion about "Execution Order" in lua filters at https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#execution-order and came up with

```lua
text = require 'text'

links = {}

function Link(el)
  links[el.target] = el.content
  return el
end

function Str(el)
  el.text = text.upper(el.text)
  return el
end

function Inlines(elems)
  for i=1,#elems,1 do
    if elems[i].tag == 'Link' then
      elems[i].content = '<====' .. links[elems[i].target] .. '====>' -- just so that I can see it in the document.
      -- elems[i].content = pandoc.Str 'hello'
    end
  end
  return elems
end

--[[ -- Explicitly force order of filters -- from "Execution Order" list...
return {
  { Link = Link,
    Str = Str,
    Inlines = Inlines
  }
}
]]
```

thinking that this will solve my problem. But somehow I cannot get this to work. I have also tried arranging the table explicitly by forcing the order (at the end of the script...commented) of called filters and yet it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The way the question is stated, I believe that one does not have to touch `Link` elements at all. The exercise should be solvable with just `Str` and `pandoc.SmallCaps` (or `Inlines` and `pandoc.SmallCaps`).

Comment: Thank you @tarleb. The problem, as far as I can tell is, that a link's content is made up of other Inlines (https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#type-link ) and I cannot stop the `Str` filter from descending into this list of `Inlines`. So, I suspect there need to be two levels of inlines (one for top level document where case transformation is applied and other for inlink traversal where no case transformation is applied) to make this work. Thanks for helping me with this.

Comment: The exercise states to modify the doc "without touching text in URLs or link titles". This is meant as a hint, but is also a bit misleading, as a `Str` filter does not affect these properties.

Comment: The exercise does not mention link captions which *will* be changed via `Str`.

Comment: So, I should comment everything except the `Str` function? I did that and put it in a file called `allcaps.lua` and ran the command `echo " Hello [Google](https://www.google.com)." | pandoc --lua-filter=./allcaps.lua --to=native` which yields `[Para [Str "HELLO",Space,Link ("",[],[]) [Str "GOOGLE"] ("https://www.google.com",""),Str "."]]` . So, I guess I was (and still am) trying to ask if there's any way to not capitalize `Str` inside the link. Is there? Anyways, thanks a bunch for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: There is. I hope to give a more complete answer within a few days when I have some time on my hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exercise asks:

> Put all the regular text in a markdown document in ALL CAPS (without touching text in URLs or link titles).

This can be done the way you describe above:

```lua
local text = require 'text'
function Str (s)
  s.text = text.upper(s.text)
  return s
end
```

This leaves URLs and link titles alone.

---

Leaving the link text alone is a bit more difficult. Pandoc Lua filters traverse the document tree in depth-first postorder, so a *Link* node will be handled only after its content has been handled. We can verify and visualize this with a simple filter like

```lua
function Inline (i)
  print(i.tag, pandoc.utils.stringify(i))
end
```

Running the above on an input like `Hello, [Free Encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org)` will produce

```
Str     Hello,
Space    
Str     Free
Space    
Str     Encyclopedia
Link    Free Encyclopedia
```

Using `Inlines` instead of `Inline` is no different: the nested elements are processed before we even know which element they belong to. This effectively means we *cannot* (easily) prevent conversions from affecting a specific subtree.

That's unfortunate (and, as the author of the Lua filter system, something I'd like to change in the future). However, not all is lost. We can work around this with a simple trick: save, then restore the original link contents:

```lua
local text = require 'text'
local links = pandoc.List()

function to_allcaps (s)
  s.text = text.upper(s.text)
  return s
end

function save_link (l)
  links:insert(l)
end

function restore_link (l)
  return links:remove(1)
end

return {
  {Link = save_link},
  {Str = to_allcaps},
  {Link = restore_link},
}
```

Here, we traverse the document three times, as indicated by the three separate filters in the returned filter list. First, we collect all links into a list; then we make everythin ALL CAPS; finally we restore the original links, thus undoing all uppercase modifications in their link captions.

Compact version:

```lua
local text = require 'text'
local links = pandoc.List{}
return {
  {Link = function (l) links:insert(l) end},
  {Str = function (s) return pandoc.Str(text.upper(s.text)) end},
  {Link = function (_) return links:remove(1) end},
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, for the detailed explanation.